# Apple search ads after app update

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-search-ads

So,

I have a search ad campaign set up.
Apple kindly make the advert for you based on your screenshots and icon etc.

I have just updated my app with a new icon, design and screenshots. Although the release is in the app store, my app campaign ads do not appear to have changed their design to reflect this.

I have tried creating a new campaign to see if it makes the ads with the new design but it seems to be the same.

Does anyone know how to trigger this change or if I just have to wait for the changes to trickle through? If so... how long?

Answer (score 0):

Having checked back occasionally I can report that this took 1 day to update in the control panel. I am still not sure how long this takes to update the ad itself.